# Fewer Integer planning variables VS More Boolean planning variables

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to model the following problem using Optaplanner:

- A product is stored in a central distribution center (CDC) -> Supply
- QuantityCDC is the available quantity in the CDC (10)
- The product is required by a regional distribution center (RDC) ->
  Demand
- QuantityRDC is the required quantity by the RDC (5)

**Model 1**

- Planning variable: CDCtoRDCquantity (quantity to be sent from CDC to
  RDC) of type Integer
- Value Range: [0, min (QuantityCDC, QuantityRDC) = 5]
- Objective function: maximize the satisfaction of the RDC

**Model 2**

- Planning variable: SelectOption Boolean variable
- List of options: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5
- Constraint : only select one option at maximum (sum SelectOption <= 1)
- Objective function: maximize the satisfaction of the RDC

**My question is** : which one of the models will be faster and scales better? Model 1 using fewer variables of type integer with well-defined value ranges or Model 2 using more variables of Boolean naturally modeling the ranges and having to add a constraint

*(The example above is an oversimplification of the real problem that has more constraints: 10-20 regional distribution centers, 1000 products, not enough supply for all demand, not enough trucks,...)*

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you can hard-code a constraint, you should prefer that.
Even the most efficient constraint will take time to process - if your data model makes it impossible for some constraints to be broken, you save time.

That said, both your options sound to me like there will be a whole lot of planning variables. While 2-3 planning variables is manageable, I definitely wouldn't go past that. Consider replacing variables with entities; such as RDCEntity, which has two variables - the CDC, and the quantity taken.